# Remove first character after a given character

Tags: unix, sed

In this case the character is "`^`".

For example in the following format with 3 columns.

From:

```
1 cccc cccc
2 cta^<t cta^<tcc
3 ccc cccc^*
4 ^]a^*c^*c ^]a^*c^*c
```

To:

```
1 cccc cccc
2 ctat ctatcc
3 ccc cccc
4 acc acc
```

I'm quite sure this is possible with sed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match your demonstration input/output, it should just be `s/\^.//g`. To match the description, you need `s/\^./\^/g` (i.e., you've described it as removing the following character, but shown removing both the caret and the following character).

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. And yes I slightly misprashed my question.

Comment: The `^` does not need to be escaped in the replacement: `s/\^./^/g` is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean `sed 's/\^.//g'` ? This removes `^` and the following character.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` solution (just offered as another Unix tool alternative, you already have `sed` solutions)

```
awk '/^/{gsub(/\^./,"", $0)};1' data.txt
```

gives

```
1 cccc cccc
2 ctat ctatcc
3 ccc cccc
4 acc acc
```